# @media not working properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website using bootstrap, but when i want to make some changes in the CSS for mobile devices, my @media doesn't work in the way i was expecting.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <hr class="style" />
            <h2>Main Title</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
h2 {font-size: 30px;}
.main {background: #000 url(..img/bg.png);}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    h2 {font-size: 20px;}
    .main {background: #fff;}
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    h2 {font-size: 24px;}
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    /* no changes yet */
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* no changes yet */
}
```

As you can see, i'm trying to remove the background img of the main div only in small screen, but it just get ignored and the img is still there. The same goes to the h2, the size is always the same (30px). I was able to change it, but i have to place the propertie inside of each '@media', which will make my css code bigger.

Is there a way to fix this?
Ps.: I already google it, was searching here but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: `background-image:none`? Perhaps a live demo using JSfiddle?

Comment: I'll try a js.fiddle. But the main problem is: The css code outside the '@media' is overlaping the code inside. Not even the h2 font-size is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

You need to add a `meta` tag to keep the viewport from virtually scaling on mobile devices

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You should also define what media the @media query is targeting:

```
h2 {font-size: 30px;}
.main {background: #000 url(http://placekitten.com/400/400);}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .main h2 {font-size: 20px;}
    .main {background: #fff;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .main h2 {font-size: 24px; color: blue;}
}

@media screen only and (max-width: 1200px) {
    /* no changes yet */
}

@media screen only and (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* no changes yet */
}
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/pimujahosete/1/edit

Comment: Ok, now it's working. I added the 'screen only' and also the meta target. Thanks man! Btw, i don't know if it can change something, but does the @medi always need to go in the very ending of the css code?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade It does, because of the way CSS styles cascade, placing the `@media` queries at the end is the only way to ensure they properly override the site's styles.